# Can I access in a SharePoint 2010 Online webpart, some webservice and do some CRUD?

Tags: web-part, web-services, sandbox-solution

I am using SharePoint Online. It is only possible to build sandbox solutions webparts. Is it possible in a sandbox solution webpart to access a webservice somewhere on the internet? I would like to do some CRUD functionality in this webpart, like show, edit, add, delete items.

This webservice is running on CRM 2011 online like :

http://mywebsite.com/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc

Answer (score 1):

You're prevented from writing to the web front end or accessing external data from **web services** or line of business systems such as SQL Server.

Reference:
http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/sharepoint-2010s-sandboxed-solutions-02-nov-2009